# Dynamic creation classes instances from array (Typescript)

Tags: typescript

I need to instantiate components on the fly.
But I don't understand how to make it work. As I understand need "cast"? Or is there a more elegant solution?

```
abstract class Component{
    abstract mount(): void;
}

class ComponentA extends Component{
    mount(){}
    send(){}
}

class ComponentB extends Component{
    mount(){}
}

type Components = {
    componentA: ComponentA,
    componentB: ComponentB
}

const componentsName = [ComponentA, ComponentB];
const instances = {} as Components;

for(const component of componentsName){
    instances[component.name] = new component(); //how to cast?
    //Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Components'.
    //No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Components'.(7053)
}

function getComponent <T extends keyof Components>(componentName: T): Components[T] {
    return instances[componentName];
}

//test 1
const componentA = instances.componentA
const componentB = instances.componentB

//test 2
const componentA2 = getComponent("componentA").send //mount | send
const componentB2 = getComponent("componentB").mount //only mount
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwgewLYAdsA7AUyIgG8AoBWhUSGeBXbAV3IAoBKALgQBu2AJYATANxUAvlSoo0GHAWJkIAQQQkAHhDKjFeQqXLU6Ldl24UZZsHp7Xps%20eiyGV5AEKadeg8uNKGjpWDggHGRkqCABPfBI3ANUMAF4EUzpYd0C1fiUjVTUAGmDaLKSvPOzVTyc5YkgkavIwADlgXAS0gG18j3UixIKvAF1JLKJG4UmIYCJYElT0qXp-YYgwSSoAM2woTgnG8vWEbG2mio32zqtShGnIOYWwbuP%20gDoiDpIRhDTSADuF3WPHECAA9OCABbYIEQbBINAQAD8d0hAFFkCROuR7gRkMJYMIIMgYggoWh6EQEAByOYxGkIWLxBAgEiwYBsOw%20fBQRZgYTEU7nZkJGmMaYAc0ZHKINMQbIQXJIoiZCOmom0TLiYr6gTANPeaPBrXVRE1WgQAslXwgbD5CABxKh9AQ%20GAME6uigwu1LPF0CljIBlN2HFVQtFtL1yUNnAA7AAGACsAGZuHVthx4ILqZKSBAY7iADwAFR8unNGAA1iQYmchv0wAA%20A7NCDXEj8Ut8Rv67ql34ZWh8u1QakPWbzRavdudsZ1SG6RoARnqM2B-Q0aUnT0W7zeOXXR3b3h3Mz3YAPp9kS8WiAATMfEIfCg%20-gh84X25wAESv8g1F-bh3jsc0IXBUJcQAHytPRn03QJPHfNIvyLcJ-1PYD3igxBIWIUlzDCIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to configure ES2019 support in the TS playground (because of `Object.fromEntries`) and I don't know if this solution would be ok for you, because it basically just uses a type-cast as you did before.

In addition there was the problem in your code that `component.name` of e.g. `ComponentA` is "ComponentA" and not as you wanted "componentA". That is fixed below, too.

```
abstract class Component{
    abstract mount(): void;
}

class ComponentA extends Component{
    mount(){}
    send(){}
}

class ComponentB extends Component{
    mount(){}
}

type Components = {
    componentA: ComponentA,
    componentB: ComponentB
}

const componentsName = [ComponentA, ComponentB] as const;
const instances = Object.fromEntries(componentsName.map((component) => [component.name[0].toLowerCase() + component.name.substring(1), new component()])) as Components;

function getComponent <T extends keyof Components>(componentName: T): Components[T] {
    return instances[componentName];
}

//test 1
const componentA = instances.componentA
const componentB = instances.componentB

//test 2
const componentA2 = getComponent("componentA").send //mount | send
const componentB2 = getComponent("componentB").mount //only mount
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ssl=20&ssc=134&pln=20&pc=73#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwgewLYAdsA7AUyIgG8AoBWhUSGeBXbAV3IAoBKALgQBu2AJYATANxUAvlSoo0GHAWJkIAQQQkAHhDKjFeQqXLU6Ldl24UZZsHp7Xps+eiyGV5AEKadeg8uNKGjpWDggHGRkqCABPfBI3ANUMAF4EUzpYd0C1fiUjVTUAGmDaLKSvPOzVTyc5YkgkavIwADlgXAS0gG18j3UixIKvAF16DCyiSElJxuEpiGAiWBJUhAB5EAArEngAOgAzKDwAUXIoYVXOcuGINo6SPdxgfE5r5ohuBBSAPgRum79PZEB7dAAMIz2EGwABlsAB3EhQTBoEg8BAAaiaFQgwIeezAbHA0HmAHNOABGbiDUjw7G3HgjbhfNBDfpgSRUA4ceDCYgIUkkCB9QIIAA8ABUfLoiPoEABrEgxbAHNmBMA-d449qdfgSvhq5LdCVjDK0KBCthQIgIeaQJYrMAAj46kgjSRRAD0nt0jQp9QW9P6GjSdsWy1We0BOQDjWjNW+toWDsj8a8sm9vsQACZY4g0+ps4nBcKPpwAEQFtTl7gEvQIb2hcgIAA+CDssrzQcCniLaRLItUFYLnhrTwsiG9xGQMXMYSAA)